# Fetch data from api(RESTful) db(mongodb) according to user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I have created an api using nodejs, express and mongodb. I am fetching data now without sending any query. But in my frontend I have an input where the user can search for a recipe. So for example if a user types "Today" i should get response related to today only. How to check that in db and retrieve data?

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.get("/dates/", (req, res) => {
    db
      .collection("dates")
      .find()
      .toArray((err, item) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send({ error: "An error has occured" });
        } else {
          res.send(item);
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Did you check the APIs or tons of tutorial on express online? https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query. For mongo you already got the `find()` method, just provide the proper query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While making the api call , pass the `dish` as query parameter

For example '/recipes/?dish="Pizza" '

and in the express use the following.

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.get("/recipes/", (req, res) => {
    let queryDish = req.query.dish; // assuming /recipes/?dish="Pizza"
    let query = { 'title' : { '$regex' : queryDish, '$options' : 'i' } }; 
    db
      .collection("recipes")
      .find(query)
      .toArray((err, item) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send({ error: "An error has occured" });
        } else {
          res.send(item);
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Anshul, my data object is as below. I have to check for the title of my object whether that query is there. `{
        "_id": "5b5446df2c89ab3d0e8d5526",
        "title": "Chicken with Mustard Cream Sauce",
        "vegetarian": false,
        "ingredients": [
            "4 whole Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts",
        ],
        "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/chickenmustarde587.jpg",
        "steps": [
            "Amount of cream and broth has slightly 
        ],
        "serving": 5,
        "cooking_time": 20
    },`

Comment: You can modify your query in that case to make a case insensitive match. Updated the answer to reflect that @BhagyaSwamy